# KendoUI using icons instead of buttons for Custom Commands

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In Kendo UI is it possible to use icons instead of buttons for the custom commands in a KendGrid?
I need this because the buttons seem to have a minimum width which is too big for my page.
Even when i specify the width it does not reduce.

```
    command: [ { name: "Edit",width: 10 ,text:"",imageClass: "k-icon k-i-pencil",
                click: function(e) {
                                    //some code
                                   }
             }]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might overwrite KendoUI definition:

```
.k-grid tbody .k-button, .k-ie8 .k-grid tbody button.k-button {
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/286F6/

Or you might try being less *aggressive* (reduce collateral effects) doing:

```
a.k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-Edit {
    min-width : 0;
}
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/286F6/1/

Or even a little less:

```
#grid a.k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-Edit {
    min-width : 0;
}
```

Where I narrow it to only one specific grid with `id="grid"`.

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/286F6/2/

But if you don't want to overwrite Kendo UI style, you still can do:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: myDataSource,
    columns: [
        {
            command: { 
                name: "Edit",
                text:"",
                imageClass: "k-icon k-i-pencil ob-icon-only",
                click: function(e) {
                    //some code
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    ],
});
```

and then:

```
$(".ob-icon-only", "#grid").parent().css("min-width", 0);
```

Check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/286F6/3/

Comment: Check the new proposed approach

Comment: When the grid is made pageable the size returns to the big buttons when I go to the second page. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Ok fixed it, has to be added in the dataBound() function.